# LDAP AD objectSID decode

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm Using `DBMS_LDAP` package to get *Users* and *Computers* with attribute `objectSid`, it is a **binary**. Using `DBMS_LDAP.GET_VALUES_BLOB` and `RAWTOHEX` I can get **HEX**. How I can convert to **SID String** (SID Structure). There is any function?

For example from `010500000000000515000000e967bb98d6b7d7bf82051e6c28060000` to `S-1-5-21-2562418665-3218585558-1813906818-1576`.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together this code using the following sources to guide me:

- Get objectGUID: https://joelitechlife.ca/2021/04/28/dbms_ldap-example/
- ObjectSid WiKi: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ObjectSID
- Converting SID Binary and String Forms: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040315-00/?p=40253

  ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_objectsid (p_samaccount IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2  AS    
       v_objectguid   VARCHAR2(100) := NULL;

       v_ldap_host    VARCHAR2(256) := 'server.domain.base';
       v_ldap_port    VARCHAR2(256) := '389';
       v_ldap_user    VARCHAR2(256) := 'CN=Oracle Services,OU=OtherAccounts,OU=Corporate,OU=Locations,DC=domain,DC=base';
       v_ldap_passwd  VARCHAR2(256) := 'password';
       v_ldap_base    VARCHAR2(256) := 'DC=domain,DC=base';

       v_result               PLS_INTEGER;
       v_session              DBMS_LDAP.session;
       v_search_attrs         DBMS_LDAP.string_collection;
       v_search_results       DBMS_LDAP.MESSAGE;
       v_entry                DBMS_LDAP.MESSAGE;
       v_values               DBMS_LDAP.BINVAL_COLLECTION;
       v_ber_element          dbms_ldap.ber_element;
       v_attr_name            VARCHAR2(256);

       l_revision number;
       l_num_dashes number;
       l_sid_issue_authority number;
       l_object_sid varchar2(100);

       function endian_value(p_string varchar2, p_endian_type varchar2)
           return varchar2
       as
           l_step number := 2;
           l_val varchar2(4000);
       begin
           if upper(p_endian_type) = 'L' then
               for i in 1..length(p_string) / 2
               loop
                   l_val := substr(p_string, i * l_step - 1, 2)||l_val;
                   dbms_output.put_line('endian of '||l_val);
               end loop;
           else
               l_val := p_string;
           end if; 

           return to_number(l_val, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
       end;

       function process_left(p_string in out varchar2, p_len int)
           return varchar2
       as
           l_rtn varchar2(100);
       begin
           l_rtn := substr(p_string, 1, p_len);
           p_string := substr(p_string, p_len + 1);

           return l_rtn;
       end;
   BEGIN

       -- Choose to raise exceptions.
       DBMS_LDAP.use_exception := TRUE;

       -- initiating the connection to the LDAP server
       v_session := DBMS_LDAP.init(hostname => v_ldap_host, portnum => v_ldap_port);

       -- binding the user
       v_result := DBMS_LDAP.simple_bind_s(ld      => v_session,
                                           dn      => v_ldap_user,
                                           passwd  => v_ldap_passwd);
       -- attribute name to search
       v_search_attrs(1) := 'objectSid';

       v_result := DBMS_LDAP.search_s( ld          => v_session,
                                       base        => v_ldap_base,
                                       scope       => DBMS_LDAP.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                       FILTER      => '(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountName='||p_samaccount||'))',
                                       attrs       => v_search_attrs,
                                       attronly    => 0,
                                       res         => v_search_results);

       -- expecting there will be only one entry matched , one attribute objectGUID only
       IF dbms_ldap.count_entries(ld => v_session, msg => v_search_results) > 0
       THEN
           v_entry := DBMS_LDAP.first_entry(ld  => v_session, msg => v_search_results);
           v_attr_name := dbms_ldap.first_attribute(ld   => v_session,
                                                   ldapentry => v_entry,
                                                   ber_elem  => v_ber_element);

           v_values := dbms_ldap.get_values_len (ld      => v_session,
                                                   ldapentry => v_entry,
                                                   attr      => v_attr_name);

           IF v_values.COUNT > 0
           THEN
               FOR i IN v_values.FIRST .. v_values.LAST
               LOOP
                   select rawtohex(v_values(i)) into v_objectguid from dual;
               END LOOP;
           END IF;   

           dbms_output.put_line(v_objectguid);  
           l_revision := to_number(process_left(v_objectguid, 2), '00');
           l_num_dashes := to_number(process_left(v_objectguid, 2), '00');
           l_sid_issue_authority := endian_value(process_left(v_objectguid, 12), 'b');

           l_object_sid := 'S-'||l_revision||'-'||l_sid_issue_authority;
           for i in 1..to_number(l_num_dashes)
           loop
               l_object_sid := l_object_sid||'-'||endian_value(process_left(v_objectguid, 8),  'l');
           end loop;

           dbms_output.put_line(l_object_sid);     

       END IF;

       IF l_object_sid IS NULL THEN 
           l_object_sid:='No_objectsid'; 
       END IF; 

       IF v_entry IS NOT NULL THEN 
           v_result := DBMS_LDAP.msgfree(v_entry);
       END IF;

       v_result := DBMS_LDAP.unbind_s(ld   => v_session);   

       RETURN l_object_sid;

       EXCEPTION
           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
               l_object_sid:='---NoSid---'; 
           RETURN l_object_sid; 

   END get_objectsid;
  ```